# Avantlink order confirmation integration with Paid membership pro

Tags: wordpress

I am having an issue integrating Avantlink Order Tracking and Order confirmation code with Paid membership pro WP.

I was sent documents from avantlinks and paid membership pro to follow and implement the task but it did not work with me.

```
Here are the codes which needs to be integrate with Paid membership pro. 
Remember I am using Divi theme on my wp site.

<script type="text/javascript">
var _AvantMetrics = _AvantMetrics || [];
_AvantMetrics.push(['order',{ order_id:'[ORDER_ID]',
amount:'[ORDER_AMOUNT]',     
state:'[BILLING_STATE]', country:'[BILLING_COUNTRY]' }]);
_AvantMetrics.push(['item',{ order_id:'[ORDER_ID]', 
parent_sku:'[ITEM_PARENT_SKU]', variant_sku:'[ITEM_VARIANT_SKU]', 
price:'[ITEM_PRICE]', qty:'[ITEM_QUANTITY]' }]);
</script>

The code above is for order confirmation and that Avantlink order 
confirmation code requires different array of variables to verify. And here 
are the paid membership pro variables that need to be set with the code 
above i am not sure how to do that

$order->membership_id
$pmpro_invoice->billing->state
$pmpro_invoice->billing->country
$pmpro_invoice->total
$pmpro_invoice->discount_code->code
$pmpro_invoice->accountnumber
```

How to use these variables in the avantlink code?

Answer (score 0):

The order confirmation code that you have pasted here contains the variables that you need to assign values from the membership variables. So consider the code as a template and all these values (ORDER_ID, ORDER_AMOUNT, BILLING_STATE etc.,) should be assigned a value which has a corresponding variable in membership pro. Please see the code below to understand how the values are passed from membership pro to Avant Metrics.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _AvantMetrics = _AvantMetrics || [];
_AvantMetrics.push(['order',{ order_id:'<?php echo $order->membership_id;?>',
amount:'<?php echo $pmpro_invoice->total;?>',     
state:'[BILLING_STATE]', country:'<?php echo $pmpro_invoice->billing->country;?>' }]);
_AvantMetrics.push(['item',{ order_id:'<?php echo $order->membership_id;?>', 
parent_sku:'[ITEM_PARENT_SKU]', variant_sku:'[ITEM_VARIANT_SKU]', 
price:'[ITEM_PRICE]', qty:'[ITEM_QUANTITY]' }]);
</script>
```

The other way of assigning the values is to create your own variables and pass those values to them. You can then assign your variables to the Avant Metrics tracking function.

```
/* here goes your custom variable */
var ORDER_ID='<?php echo $order->membership_id;?>';
```

and when you follow the above method, please make a note on how you assign the custom variable to the AvantMetrics function.

```
_AvantMetrics.push(['order',{ order_id:ORDER_ID,
```

Please try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hello James! Thank you so very much! Is the code above you wrote will help me verifying avantlink?

Comment: Sorry to know about that. But can you please paste the code here. Let me see what went wrong.